# Why does literature call the response of an antenna array the array "manifold" vector?

Tags: antenna-array, topology, beamforming

Van Trees' *Optimum Array Processing* and other works (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_array#Spectrum-based_beamforming)) refer to an antenna array's response (shifts in phase and differences in gain due to the angle of reception) at each element as the array "manifold" vector.

Why?

I can see how it might be considered a mapping that carries the received signal vectors from the elements' observation space to a common analytic space, but I do not understand what makes it a manifold or why a topological concept would be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get hung up on terminology. Manifold can mean manifold (ie many) things.

The topological concept is definitely not being used here. Topology is only interested in the connectivity of things, not their distance. In a beamforming array, distance is a vital parameter.

I think the 'many' meaning is more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe, but Google search turns up many articles like [The impact of sensor positioning on the array manifold](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1229891) that appear to be using the topological meaning of the word.

Comment: @gibbss The abstract in that link of yours mentioned 'geometry' six times, and 'topology' zero times, an infinite ratio, so I think I'll stick with my characterisation for the moment.